# Как настроить МФУ Xerox 3100MFP?

Tags: windows-7

Здравствуйте!

Дома стоит МФУ Xerox 3100MFP. НА windows xp рфботает прекрасно, на Windows 7 sp1 64x не работает сканер. Как настроить сканер в МФУ Xerox 3100MFP на Windows 7 sp1 64x?

Спасибо!

PS Дравйвера с Off сайта не помогли.

Comment: **Update!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для устранения данной неполадки нужно обновить прошивку самого мфу.